# Fingerprint reader invoked for login but not for sudo

Tags: 22.04, sudo, fingerprint-reader

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Framework 13

I have enabled the fingerprint reader in Settings→Users and it is invoked whenever I start the laptop, but it is not asked for in Terminal when I am using `sudo` or whenever the Ubuntu pop-up window asks for authentication. I have changed my keyring pw to null, and in a previous installation of Ubuntu `sudo` did direct me to use the FP reader. Any clues of what I should look for?

- Host: Laptop AB
- BIOS: INSYDE Corp. 3.17 (10/27/2022)
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
- DE: GNOME 42.5 (wayland)
- Kernel: Linux 5.19.0-41-generic
- Shell: bash 5.1.16
- WM: Mutter
- CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 4.7GHz
- GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
- GPU Driver: i915
- Memory: 4.23 GiB / 15.41 GiB (27%)
- Disk (/): 13G / 228G (6%)
- Network: Wifi6
- Bluetooth: Intel Corp. AX210

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer involves configuring PAM, but as I am not much good at coding I kept digging for an easier answer and I think I found it in this article: https://forty.sh/posts/2021-02-19-enabling-fingerprint-authentication/

The solution is to issue this command, I have no idea why or how it works, at least it worked for me:

sudo  pam-auth-update --enable fprintd